# appending values to a list from list

Tags: python

```
 l1= [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[1,2]]
 l2= [[4,9],[2,9],[2,2],[6,3]]
```

I want to append second value of list 2 to list 1 if first value of l2 matches last value of l1.

new l1= [[1,2,9],[3,4,9],[5,6,3],[1,2,2]]

Comment: The rules you want to apply are not clear.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as follows:

```
l1= [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
l2= [[2,4],[4,9],[2,2]]

newL = [v1 + [v2[1]] for v1,v2 in zip(l1,l2) if v2[0] == v1[1]]

print(newL) # [[1, 2, 4], [3, 4, 9]]
```

Comment: what if there are more lists than 3 each?

Comment: Not sure if I understand, but if you have more you can use relative counting from the end of list: `newL = [v1 + [v2[-1]] for v1,v2 in zip(l1,l2) if v2[0] == v1[-1]]`

Comment: If you want to check all possible combinations, use this: `newL = [v1 + [v2[-1]] for v1 in l1 for v2 in l2 if v2[0] == v1[-1]]`

Comment: I want it to check one per each. The code above returns 6 lists instead of 4.

Comment: You can always remove duplicates using `newL_unique = set(map(tuple, newL))`. Or remove duplicate sublits in l1 and l2 befor doing a search in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

```
[x+(y[1:]) for x,y in zip(l1,l2) if x[1] == y[0]]
```